# Optimizing/Alternate to Cross Apply

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, optimization, cross-apply

I need help in optimizing following SQL query.

Table 1 : 62000 records

```
Col 1   Col 2     Col 3 
1       X, Y      A, B  
2       L, M, N   P, Q, R 
3       G         H
```

Table 2 : 2000 records

```
Col 1   Col 2
1       One
2       Two
```

Output Required:

```
Col1   Col2  Col3  Col4
1      X     A     One
1      Y     B     One
2      L     P     Two
2      M     Q     Two
2      N     R     Two
3      G     H
```

Current Performance: 23-30 sec

Current Query:

```
SELECT    
    e.[ID], e.[Title], a.id, a.val, b.id, b.val, 
FROM [dbo].[Table 1] e 
CROSS apply dbo.KDSplit(Col2, ' , ') a 
CROSS apply dbo.KDSplit(e.Col3, ' , ') b 
LEFT JOIN Table2 k ON k.SeriesCode = e.SeriesCode
    WHERE a.id = b.id AND isDate(b.val) = 1
```

---

Function that returns id and value:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[KDSplit]
(
  @delimited nvarchar(max),
  @delimiter nvarchar(100)
) RETURNS @t TABLE
(
  id int identity(1,1),
  val nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
  declare @xml xml
  set @xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@delimited,@delimiter,'</r><r>') + '</r></root>'
  insert into @t(val)
  select
    r.value('.','varchar(max)') as item
  from @xml.nodes('//root/r') as records(r)
  RETURN
END
```

Comment: Fix the data structure.  That is, use junction tables instead of strings to stores lists of odd.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is NOT the CROSS APPLY,

but you really should consider to switch to a different **SPLIT** function..

if you use the well known **[DelimitedSplit8K]** your query execution time will drop from 25 secs to less than a second..

I have tested it with random data, 60000 recs in Table1, 2000 recs in Table2 and each col2 and col3 with random 1-3 letters

I hope this help